# Is there a PDF document of the current core Perl 5 version (eg. 5.34)?

Tags: perl, perldoc

This used to be a super simple no-brainer. For example, if I were looking for python documentation, I'd first do a google search for:

> python documentation pdf

... and voila! The first result is exactly what's needed: A single downloadable containing PDFs for Python.  There are 27 files, but one
of them documents Python core.

But I'm not looking for a comprehensive Python documentation.  I'm looking for the same type of document, but for Perl.  Doing the same google search for:

> Perl documentation pdf

(or similar queries) would show references to either [perl.org](https://www.perl.org/docs.html), [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/), [perl.developpez.com](https://perl.developpez.com/documentations/en/5.20.0/), [perl.mines-albi.fr](http://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl-all-en-5.8.5.pdf), etc, but none gives a download link for a single comprehensive PDF that documents core Perl.

There used to be a downloadable large PDF file (built from a large manpage), which has disappeared since some 5.x version. I know that all the pieces of this core Perl document are available online in perl.org, perldoc.perl.org, and offline in perldoc. That's wonderful
for people who want to repeatedly manually query on a terminal or browser. I'm simply asking
where can I find a single PDF file that contains the entire core
Perl documentation, in the same way that there's one for:

- Python (as mentioned above. See: https://docs.python.org/3/archives/python-3.9.7-docs-pdf-letter.zip, in the zip as "reference.pdf")
- MySQL (https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-8.0-en.pdf)
- JavaScript/ECMAScript (https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_12th_edition_june_2021.pdf)

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

PLEASE NOTE: I'm NOT looking for "book recommendations," as the SO review of my question had asserted (and subsequently labeled the question as inappropriate). I know the books. If I wanted
them, I would have bought them from Amazon.

Comment: The `perldoc` program?

Comment: https://books.goalkicker.com/PerlBook/PerlNotesForProfessionals.pdf maybe this?

Comment: @shawn:  Thanks for the perldoc  reference.   I can only get individual "man page" style text documents for individual sections.   Doing a "perldoc perltoc > perltoc.txt"  gives a large text file that I can browse using "less",  but it's not a PDF file, and not the entire Perl doc.   Do you know the perldoc options to generate an up-to-date version of this doc: https://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl-all-en-5.8.5.pdf ?

Comment: The `perldoc` utility (included) and the `man` utility (where available) both allow you to access the documentation for your installed build of perl and the modules installed for it. Alternatively, the documentation for both current and past versions of Perl is found at http://perldoc.perl.org. And the documentation for both current and past versions of modules can be found on https://metacpan.org. The documentation is not just one file, PDF or otherwise.

Comment: Re "*and not the entire Perl doc*", Correct, the entire documentation is not just one file. It never has been just one file (as far as I know, which means it hasn't been for at least 22 years).

Comment: Re "*Do you know the perldoc options to generate an up-to-date version of this doc:*", That's an entirely different question than the one that was asked. The document lists at least some of the tools used. What have you tried? What problem are you having?

Comment: @IvanDimitrov - Thanks for PerlNotesForProfessionals.  It's pretty good, and I will use it as a quick ref.  Definitely an improvement on the Vromans ref, which is great, but decades old. PerlNotesForProfessionals covers up to Perl 5.26, but I'm still looking for the full docset for Perl 5.30 .

Comment: You can use `roffitall` in the perl source to generate a postscript document. That should be easy to turn into pdf. See `perldoc perlutil`.

Comment: Back in the mid 90's I had a binder with printouts of all the core perl docs that was probably made with it. But just using `perldoc` to look up specific stuff is so much more manageable and convenient...

Comment: @ikegami - Thanks very much for those refs.  I'm looking to generate/download an up-to-date Perl 5.30 or later of this: https://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl-all-en-5.8.5.pdf .  I know that I can lookup specific sections in perldoc.perl.org, but I'd prefer the convenience and speed of using a single PDF file.

Comment: There's also https://metacpan.org/dist/pod2pdf/view/bin/pod2pdf

Comment: Re "*I'd prefer the convenience and speed of using a single PDF file*", I've already said the docs is NOT just a single file

Comment: Or just buy Programming Perl if you want an all in one reference.

Comment: Re "*There used to be a downloadable large PDF file called the "perlbook."*", Maybe, but it wasn't the Perl documentation. [perlbook](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.6.0/perlbook) circa 2000, Current [perlbook](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlbook). You are probably referring to an electronic copy of [Programming Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Perl)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's suggestions.  Really, I'm looking for a single file. I know that I can use perldoc to query the documentation, but nothing beats having a single file like  perl.mines-albi.fr/perl-all-en-5.8.5.pdf  and using a good "tabbed" PDF viewer with persistent bookmarking (eg. SumatraPDF).

Comment: Well, I wonder how much time you spend in scrolling a book of 1714 pages? `perldoc` does it much faster and always in your hand, what is more important - that it does not require anything like PDF reader or GUI.

Comment: Perhaps you can find section [Tutorials](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl#Tutorials) useful.

Comment: @PolarBear - When I don't have a GUI, yes I know that I can use the man pages, perldoc, perlpod, etc.  When I do have a GUI, I prefer to have a single PDF reference.  Don't knock it until you've tried it.  I use the SumatraPDF browser, which features: in-window tabs for separate PDFs,  Chapter Bookmarks (as created by the PDF author), and persistent user "Favorite/bookmarks".   I'm a developer from the Unix SystemV days, and NOTHING beats having this ability to reference key documents is a snap.

Answer (score 4):

You were looking for the current perl documentation and you got it.
**perldoc.perl.org** has it.

There's no single pdf, single html or single chm anymore (though various libraries to produce one).
perldoc for core perl consists of hundreds of documents, and with all the CPAN libraries you are at >100.000 documents. Plus there exist dozen or so perl books which are available as pdf.

There's no single perlbook, rather perlbook has a list of most books about perl.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question to make clear what I'm looking for: The CORE Perl documentation in a single PDF. There used to be one.  By "core" I mean what's part of the language. If I were to "git clone" the current Perl 5 source and build it, that would create the core Perl.

Comment: What was it in my question that led to the conclusion that I was "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries"?

Comment: @algn2: Well, The CORE Perl documentation would consist of only 1779 PDF's then.
With 253 core PDF's, the rest are PDF's for the core libs.